# How we can set topic for group chat in Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

Not able to set topic for group chat using setTopic method of slack api.
Getting below error :
{
"ok": false,
"error": "method_not_supported_for_channel_type"
}

Can anyone please suggest how we can set topic for group chat in slack.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is it a private channel or mpdm ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct scopes for the type of channel you are targeting, i.e. private channel, im, mpdm. Also make sure that the authenticated user or the bot user (depending on the token you're using) is a member of that channel.